# Erro No suitable driver found ao conectar com javaDB

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, conexão

Criei um banco de dados usando o derby do netbeans do javadb, depois criei ma conexao na porta 1527 com o nome do Banco sendo TESTE. Feito isso, criei a string de conexao abaixo que deveria me conectar ao Banco TESTE, mas com o codigo abaixo nao consigo me conectar.

```
package javadata;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Djafta
 */
public class JavaData {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //PARAMETROS("jdbc:derby://host:port//DB;user=?;password=?");
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTE","root","root");
            System.out.println("Conectado com sucesso...");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problema de conexao: " + ex);
        }


        //Statement sql = conn.createStatement();


    }

}
```

Agora esta dando o erro asseguir depois de adicionar o ex.printStackTrace();:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTE
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at javadata.JavaData.main(JavaData.java:25)
```

Comment: Dá algum erro? Se não der, experimente colocar `ex.printStackTrace();` dentro o catch para ver se a exceção está sendo capturada.

Comment: Agora esta dando o erro: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTE

Comment: Dafta edite a pergunta adicionando a pilha de erros do prinstacktrace, parece que já da pra saber a causa.

Comment: Esta feito. percebi que ajuda na organizacao da pagina

Comment: Viu minha resposta abaixo?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [este post no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3818210/5524514), o problema pode ser dois:

- o driver pode não estar sendo carregado corretamente;
- a URL de conexão do JDBC está mal formulada.

Se a base de dados ainda não foi criada, experimente adicionar `create=true` ao final da url de conexão, assim o banco criará, caso não exista. Sem esse parâmetro, se o base de dados nao existir, o java vai disparar uma exceção mesmo. No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
"jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TESTE;create=true"
```

Por padrão, o banco é criado onde o serviço do banco foi iniciado, seria interessante você especificar o local de criação do banco, para conseguir depois replicá-lo ou editá-lo com algum outro programa. Dando um exemplo de um banco criado numa pasta chamada *database* no disco C:\:

```
"jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:/database/TESTE;create=true"
```

Verifique também se o jar `derbyclient.jar` foi adicionado no classpath do projeto, pois esse jar é o driver do javadb, necessário para o java conseguir fazer a conexao com este banco.

O driver pode ser encontrado [neste link](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html), conforme sua versão do java.

---

<sub>P.S.: apesar de ter respostas no link indicado pedindo para registrar o driver, esta ação não é mais necessária desde que se esteja utilizando jdk 6 ou  versões superiores, pois a partir desta versão da API já vem com uma versão do JDBC que registra automaticamente o driver conforme adicionado no classpath.</sub>